# Android room aggregating data by day month or year

Tags: android, sql, aggregation, android-room

I'm trying to graph data that I've stored using Room. For this I have a Session entity and then 1 to many relations for the session such as number of steps, blood pressure and oxygen levels that are recorded during the session.

For the session I store the start time and I'd like to be able to group sessions by this date (into either day/month/year bins). For each time interval I then need to get the averages for steps, blood pressure and oxygen levels to show on the graph. For example, multiple sessions could happen on 4/23/2018, but I would like to just get the average for the day.

**Session**

```
@Entity
public class Session implements Serializable {
    public final static String TABLE = "Session";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long sid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "startTimestamp")
    private Date startTimestamp;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "endTimestamp")
    private Date endTimestamp;

    public long getSid() { return sid; }
    public Date getStartTimestamp() { return startTimestamp; }
    public Date getEndTimestamp() { return endTimestamp; }
    public long getDuration() { return endTimestamp.getTime() - startTimestamp.getTime(); }

    public void setSid(long sid) { this.sid = sid; }
    public void setStartTimestamp(Date timestamp) { this.startTimestamp = timestamp; }
    public void setEndTimestamp(Date timestamp) { this.endTimestamp = timestamp; }

    @android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
    public interface SessionDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE)
        List<Session> getAll();

        @Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE)
        List<SessionWithRelations> getAllWithRelations();

        @Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY :orderBy")
        List<SessionWithRelations> getAllWithRelations(String orderBy);

        @Insert
        long insert(Session session);

        @Update
        void update(Session session);

        @Delete
        void delete(Session session);
    }
}
```

**SessionOxygen**

```
@Entity
public class SessionOxygen implements Serializable {
    public final static String TABLE = "SessionOxygen";

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sid")
    private long sid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "oxygen")
    private int oxygen;

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public long getSid() { return sid; }
    public Date getTimestamp() { return timestamp; }
    public int getOxygen() { return oxygen; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public void setSid(long sid) { this.sid = sid; }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) { this.timestamp = timestamp; }
    public void setOxygen(int oxygen) { this.oxygen = oxygen; }

    @android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
    public interface OxygenDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE sid=:sid")
        List<SessionOxygen> getAllForSession(int sid);

        @Insert
        long[] insertAll(List<SessionOxygen> oxygens);

        @Insert
        long insert(SessionOxygen oxygen);
    }

}
```

**Session POJO**

```
public class SessionWithRelations {
    @Embedded
    public Session session;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "sid", entityColumn = "sid", entity = SessionBloodPressure.class)
    public List<SessionBloodPressure> bloodPressureList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relation(parentColumn = "sid", entityColumn = "sid", entity = SessionWeight.class)
    public List<SessionWeight> weightList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relation(parentColumn = "sid", entityColumn = "sid", entity = SessionOxygen.class)
    public List<SessionOxygen> oxygenList = new ArrayList<>();

    public int averageOxygen() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (oxygenList.size() > 0) {
            for (SessionOxygen oxygen : oxygenList) {
                sum += oxygen.getOxygen();
            }
            return sum / oxygenList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int averageWeight() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (oxygenList.size() > 0) {
            for (SessionWeight weight : weightList) {
                sum += weight.getWeight();
            }
            return sum / weightList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int averageDiastolic() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (oxygenList.size() > 0) {
            for (SessionBloodPressure bloodPressure : bloodPressureList) {
                sum += bloodPressure.getDiastolic();
            }
            return sum / weightList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int averageSystolic() {
        int sum = 0;
        if (oxygenList.size() > 0) {
            for (SessionBloodPressure bloodPressure : bloodPressureList) {
                sum += bloodPressure.getSystolic();
            }
            return sum / weightList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I just switched my entire app over to using Room but I feel like this would be pretty easy with a raw query. I'm not sure if that's even possible with Room however. I looked at the RawQuery docs but that looks to only allow queries to be generated at run time but still return only entities and I need custom columns returned.

```
// Group by month and get average Oxygen level for each month with data
select s.startTimestamp, AVG(o.oxygen) as oxygenAverage
    from Session s
    left join SessionOxygen o on s.sid = o.sid
    group by DATE_FORMAT(s.startTimestamp, "%m-%Y");
```

I have a feeling I have to do something with a POJO class but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I think my other option is to aggregate it in code but that would be highly inefficient and messy.